# How to receive notification from server in android using PHP MySql

Tags: java, php, android

I am developing a mobile app in android. The app is supposed to receive a notification when the user fills in a particular form. How can I achieve that functionality?

Comment: heard about FCM?

Answer (score 0):

Integrate google push notification in your android application.Send IMEI number to the php side on first login of the application. I think the form is to be filled from php side as per the question. If that form filling is completed then php side can get that success or failure condition, then ask the php side to give back the push notification to the application side based on your IMEI no: if the form filling is success.